# Pyrocms stopped rendering after page refresh

Tags: php, caching, pyrocms

Currently, I'm working on a website that built with Pyrocms (the website is not mine, and I'm new to Pyrocms).

The problem is:

- On the **first load**, the layout will be displayed, but without any image.
- When I try to refresh the page (**second load**), everything disappear, just blank page.

But when I try to install it on my local machine, the site just working well without any problem.

I've been checking any error possibilities from cache folder permissions, `.htaccess` file, and clearing the cache, but it seems nothing is work.

When I trace the rendering process (grey bar with number in my screenshot), the process stopped on number **3**.

On: `/system/cms/core/MY_Controller.php` `line 75`, after this code, the rendering process stopped:

```
$this->load->library(array('session', 'settings/settings'));
```

Here is a screenshot:

**FIRST LOAD:**
[image: first load]

**AFTER REFRESH:**
[image: second load]

Any advice or help would be appreciated.

Comment: anything in system/cms/logs? or the log files of your webserver?

Comment: oh and check if the mcrypt extension is installed on the webserver. loading the session library could casue the whole thing to crash if it isn't.

Comment: thanks @mgrueter for your response, i've been checked value for **mcrypt** these are the current setting values, **mcrypt support** ---> **enabled**
**mcrypt_filter support** ---> **enabled**, but **mcrypt.algorithms_dir**, and **mcrypt.modes_dir** setting are **no value**, oh, and there is no logs...

Comment: i dont know what is the problem, but if i clear browser cache, the cycle back to the screenshot i attached (no image, then blank page)

Comment: is the production mode enabled? check .htaccess for "SetEnv PYRO_ENV production" and disable if neccessary. and also change 'log_threshold' in system/cms/config/config.php to 2. There should be any kind of log or error message then

Comment: @mgrueter, sorry for my late reply... i've been checked the `.htaccess` for `SetEnv PYRO_ENV production` and the line is already disabled. i also change the config log_threshold to 2, but still no error logs, maybe that means there is no error at all... so maybe the problem here is server related? because in my local machine the site just working well.

Comment: yes, looks like its a server related issue. The problem is likey caused by the session library. So you might want to debug there and identifiy the actual line that causes the problem in the session libraries constructor (system/codeigniter/libraries/Session/Session.php). Alternatively you could try to change the session settings in system/cms/config/config.php - set a different driver etc. It's very strange that you don't get some kind of log. With a treshold of 2 there should be plenty of debug messages in the system/cms/logs/ log files.